# How can I change height of a Table element with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, height

I can change `bgcolor` and `width` but not `height`. What's the problem?

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('tabelID').bgColor = 'green';
  document.getElementById('tabelID').height = 50;
  document.getElementById('tabelID').width = 100;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='change();'>change now</button>
<table id='tabelID' bgcolor='red' height='20' width='20'></table>
```

Comment: You should use CSS rather than the obsolete table attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The `bgcolor`, `width`, and `height` attributes on `table` have been deprecated. You should use the CSS properties `background-color`, `width`, and `height` instead. Here's an updated example that changes the table by toggling a CSS class:

```js
function toggleChanges() {
    document.getElementById('tabelID').classList.toggle('larger');
}
```

```css
.mytable {
    background-color: red;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.mytable.larger {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='toggleChanges();'>toggle changes</button>
<table id='tabelID' class='mytable'></table>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers. They all worked fine. Great!

Comment: @StefanHesman if my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it (by clicking the gray checkmark underneath the answer score), thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I will let you this code running,  you need to use css, and for height and width define a metric (px, %, ...), maybe that could help you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick='change();'>change now</button>
<table style="background-color:red ;height:20px ;width:20px;" id='tabelID' ></table>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function change() {
   document.getElementById('tabelID').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   document.getElementById('tabelID').style.height = "50px";
   document.getElementById('tabelID').style.width = "100px";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties and attributes don't always have the same names.

The `height` attribute corresponds to the `clientHeight` property, but this is a read-only property. Use `setAttribute()` to change the attribute.

But as I mentioned in a comment, it would be better to use CSS than the obsolete attributes.

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById('tabelID').bgColor = 'green';
  document.getElementById('tabelID').setAttribute("height", 50);
  document.getElementById('tabelID').setAttribute("width", 100);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='change();'>change now</button>
<table id='tabelID' bgcolor='red' height='20' width='20'></table>
```